How to chant the gyan Medha suktam?
In a YouTube video by swami samarpananda , I came across of suktam called gyan Medha suktam , which can enhance intelligence . What is the proper way to chant it and can it be chanted in mind or do we have to do it aloud? Thank you.

Please give the answer to this question as I donot want a fruitless action to be performed.
